# OS X client for Google Docs/Drive, incorporating the real-time collaboration feature?

Tags: osx, text-editor, collaboration, google-drive

I have several documents that are collaboratively edited in Google Drive. I'd prefer to use a more responsive, easier-to-open desktop client to edit these documents.

It must:

- Be able to see all my Google Drive documents
- Be able to make edits to these documents in real time
- Take edits from my collaborators in real time and show them to me as the web versions does.

It would be nice to have the real time chat feature, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: If I understand correctly, app that shows Google Drive web is enough? (I do understand just opening web page to browser tab is not too nice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When my employer moved to Google Apps, I tried using [RocketDocs](http://rocketdocsapp.com/) but in the end moved back to Chrome. It fills all your requirements, though. Currently $2.99 from [Mac app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rocketdocs-google-docs-client/id505954267?ls=1&mt=12). There's also iOS version, but I have no experience with that.

Nice things compared to just opening the Drive on web browser tab:

- Uploads integrated nicely to OS X (not a big difference, though)
- Better keyboard shortcuts
- Acts like Mac app (launcher icon, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> etc.)

However, it just opens Google Drive web, so there's nothing special about it. For example, offline mode is same as with Drive web, and UI is obviously exactly the same. On the positive side, this way, all new features and updates are there as soon as Google pushes those out.